# Why does the size of a file drop an order of magnitude after it's been copied?

Tags: windows, windows-10, copy-paste

I've noticed a peculiarity when I copy a video file(though this could apply to other files) from a USB drive to Windows 10 Hard Drive.

While the file is being copied, the size (from the Size field in Details view) is, for example, 1,000,000 KB. But when the file is done being copied, the size drops to 100,000 KB.

What is going on?

Edit:
This does not happen all the time. It seems to happen to large files.

Comment: And you're copying the video file from your Windows 10 hard drive to where?

Comment: @KinameCole I'm copying from a USB to my Windows 10 hard drive.

Comment: What size does the UBS drive has and which file system does it use? If you click on a drive in the overview in the explorer you usually get that information on the bottom half where it also tells you about the disk usage etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing. From what I understand is that when the data is stored on the hard drive, it stored as quantized blocks. The various formatting scheme has various block sizes. If your Windows file system uses NTFS and your USB stick uses FAT32, then a certain amount of data will be spread over a number of blocks, that  can end up a different size on different storage devices. Although the original file remains the same.